# Trying to pass json hash to postgres json column results in null value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-api

I'm playing with the Rails API server and I'm trying to pass a JSON object to the database, but it keeps resulting in a null value.

The schema is simple:

```
create_table "notes", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "title"
  t.string   "created_by"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.json     "clients"
end
```

Here's what I'm posting in Postman

```
{
    "created_by": "1",
    "title": "I'm another note",
    "clients": {
        "client1": {
            "name": "name 1",
            "role": "role 1"
        },
        "client 2": {
            "name": "name 2",
            "role": "role 2"
        }
    }
}
```

and this returns

```
{
  "id": 14,
  "title": "I'm another note",
  "created_by": "1",
  "created_at": "2017-06-14T10:52:00.226Z",
  "updated_at": "2017-06-14T10:52:00.226Z",
  "clients": null
}
```

If I send the client key/value pairs as `"clients": "some client"` it will write no problem. Am I just passing the wrong data in Postman or is it something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your strong parameters have to be adjusted to expect and pass a json.

To allow a json with any keys to be accepted, you would set note_params as

```
def note_params
  params.require(:mote).permit(:title, :created_by).tap do |white_list|
    white_list[:clients] = params[:note][:clients].permit! if params[:note][:clients]
  end
end
```

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks